# Lambda ==> RDS ==> QuickSight

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, aws-security-group

## What I'm trying to do

I am working on a lambda function which will simply register some metadata about files which are uploaded onto an s3 bucket. This is not about actually processing the data in the files yet. To start with, I just want to register the fact that certain files have been uploaded or not. Then I want to connect that metadata to QuickSight just so that we can have a nice visual about which files have been uploaded.

## What I've done so far

This part is fairly easy:

- Some simply python code with the pymysql module
- Chalice to manage the process of creating and updating the lambda function
- I created the database

## Where I'm stuck

- QuickSight is somehow external to AWS in general. So I had to create the RDS (mysql) in the DMZ of our VPC.
- I have configured the security group so that the DB is accessible both from QuickSight and from my own laptop.

But the lambda function can't connect.

- I configured the right policy for the role, so that the lambda can connect with IAM
- I tested that policy with the simulator
- But of course the lambda function is going to have some kind of dynamic IP and that needs to be in the security group

## Any Ideas ??

I am even thinking about this right?

Answer (score 1):

Two things.

1. You shouldn't have to put your RDS in a DMZ. See this article about granting QuickSight access to your RDS: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/enabling-access-rds.html
2. In order for a lambda to access something in a VPC (like and RDS instance) the lambda must have a VPC configuration. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-vpc.html

Comment: Jason 
Connecting to the DB from QuickSight: pretty sure we did all the things as explained in the first article you cite, but it only worked when we changed the subnets to the DMZ (will check on Monday).
As to the second article, there were a few permissions missing which were not added by Chalice. If I add those permissions, should it work even if my DB is still in the DMZ?

Comment: The lambda configuration part should work regardless of where the RDS is, assuming you have the correct security groups in place.